# Unable to use an ajax post request in a cordova android project

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

I'm creating an app using Cordova 3.4 (aka Phonegap).

I created an **Ajax form** (to send **text AND file**) which work fine in any browser.

But, when I try to do the same in the android app it doesn't work at all.

I've already think about `<access origin="*" />` in the XML. And I saw this one [Unable to post to Restful API through Ajax using android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556668/unable-to-post-to-restful-api-through-ajax-using-android-phone) but it didn't solve my problem. (the difference is that I'm sending a file)

Any idea to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upload your file, you need to use file transfer phonegap plugin.

Download and install this plugin into your cordova project.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Then put this code into your project

Javascript
    imageURI = "your_file_location_in_device";

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
var params = new Object();
params.param1 = "param1";
params.param2 = "param2";
options.params = params;
options.chunkedMode = false;
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, "https://example.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);

function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code, null, 'Alert', 'OK');
}
```

PHP

```
print_r($_FILES);
$new_image_name = $imageLink.".jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/".$new_image_name);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I got the file plugin but no the file-transfer one. One more question : how can I get imageURI value from a classic html form?

Comment: you need to use camera phonegap plugin to get imageURI